# Replace all for special characters

Tags: microsoft-word-2013, special-characters

does anybody know how you could replace all characters by a special character. Say, I would like to replace all *s by x (not x, but the multiplication sign also known as cross product sign). There are dozens of these in the document. When I open the replace all dialog, it doesn't let me to copy paste the special character in the 'Replace with' box.

Comment: Have you tried to use MS Word's Insert Special Characters dropdown for the find and replace textbox?

Comment: Try `Alt`+`0215` to type `×` _Multiplication Sign_ ×